# Android標準ライブラリで対応しているバーコード規格は何ですか？

Tags: java

Aandroidの標準ライブラリで対応しているバーコードの一覧の公式情報を頂きたいのですがありますでしょうか？
また、医療用医薬品 GS1データバーの規格に対応しておりますでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://discussionsjapan.apple.com/thread/110194642

Answer (score 2):

以下ですね。
https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview

また、公式ページではないですが、「Android バーコード 標準api」でGoogle検索すると、私の環境では公式へのリンク付きの分かりやすいページが1番に出てきましたよ。
https://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=7309